# getting rss feeds in my website

Tags: php, rss, gmail

The code below gets rss feeds from yahoo and it works but I have a little problem, when I rub the code, it returns the feeds but it also gives me an error like -

**Undefined offset: 1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/feedbackFtms/rss.php on line 8**

`line 8 is -`
`$foundImg = $findImg[1];`

```
<div class="feed">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/profilepage.css">

    <?php
        function getImageFromContext($context){

        $findImg = explode('<img src="',$context);
        $foundImg = $findImg[1];
        $findExt = explode('.jpg',$foundImg);
        $getIMG = $findExt[0].'.jpg';
        return $getIMG;
        }

       function getFeed($url){
        $x = simplexml_load_file($url);
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
            echo "<li><img src='".getImageFromContext($entry->description)."' /><a href='{$entry->link}' title='{$entry->title}'>{$entry->title}</a></li><br>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
        }
        getFeed("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/entertainment");
    ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: The problem is on line 7, where the `explode` isn't finding anything to explode on.

Comment: hey mike, please explain more to me...not really an expert on php n stuffs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some articles don't have image.

you can change a little bit your code as is and I guess it will work but for this more convenient to use regular expressions.

```
<?php
function getImageFromContext($context){

    $findImg = explode('<img src="',$context);
    if(isset($findImg[1])){
        $foundImg = $findImg[1];
        $findExt = explode('.jpg',$foundImg);
        $getIMG = '<img src="' . $findExt[0].'.jpg' . '" />';

        return $getIMG;
    }

    return '';
    }

function getFeed($url){
    $x = simplexml_load_file($url);

    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
        echo "<li>".getImageFromContext($entry->description)."<a href='{$entry->link}' title='{$entry->title}'>{$entry->title}</a></li><br>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    getFeed("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/entertainment");

?>

</div>
```

---

Comment: thank you Artak..it works now..i appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
        echo "<li><img src='".getImageFromContext('<img src="'.$entry->description)."' /><a href='{$entry->link}' title='{$entry->title}'>{$entry->title}</a></li><br>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
```

I am not sure if you need the last two lines before the return in the getImageFromContext function.

Comment: hi scrooj..it gets rid of the error for sure but now...it does not display the thubnail images, it displays the default error image icon.

Comment: hey marvel,just made an edit..should be fine now.

Comment: hey Scrooj..thanks for your help too..you have been wonderful. It now works.